# View MS Word as HTML in a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ms-word

Hi
Am developing a small search engine kind of application. It searches for contents in word documents. I need to implement a "view as html" option as in gmail. When I click the link to the doc, it should open as a html page in a new browser. Is there any way to achieve this?

I was able to open the word doc in an iframe, but that does not suit my purpose.

My application uses Asp.Net and C#. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Vignesh

Comment: See this, it may or may not help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694090/saving-multiple-word-documents-as-html-through-office-api

Comment: @Tony : It may be possible that my deployment network may not have internet access. Am not sure if I may be able to use google docs without internet.

Comment: @Matt : Yeah. The link you sent was pretty useful. Thanks a lot Mat.

Answer (score 0):

The easy, slow, memory-intensive, unscalable, unscalable (needs to be said twice) way of doing it would be to use the office COM API to load the file and save it as html (or text actually since all you want to do is a search on it), but I really doubt you can pull this off in even a moderately used web site.

Throwing that aside, you're left with open source parsers or using the `IFilter` interface to do it. I found an example of the latter: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/316480-reading-text-from-ms-word-files-in-c

Comment: I have no issues searching for the text inside the document. I use Solr and its extracthandler to extract the text from the word document. Now I need a way to display the word document to the searcher when he clicks the link. I thought displaying it as html will be great...

Comment: Oh... well... in that case I have no suggestions. This isn't trivial at all.